# how to get the last column using xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

So I have an excel file that contains data in this format:
[image]
I want to read this data using xlwings and I want this to be dynamic that means if I add the data in the or middle of this then it should be able to do this. I have tried this so far but it is not working properly:

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App(visible=False)
    try:
        wb1 = app.books.open(commonInputs)
        sheet = wb2.sheets['Regional Transmission Links']
        lastCell = generatorSheet.range('A1').end('right').last_cell.column
        name = sheet.range('C5:L'+str(lastCell)).value
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Something awful happened!")
        print(e)
    finally:
        app.quit()
        app.kill()
```

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 7):

I hope I understood your question right: How to get the last column of your table using xlwings? You can get it as follows.

**Last column as integer**

```
sheet["A1"].expand("right").last_cell.column
```

[`.column`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.column) gives you the column of the cell as a number (1-indexed), e.g. for column `C` it gives you `3`.

**Last column as letter**

```
sheet["A1"].expand("right").last_cell.address.split("$")[1]
```

[`.address`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.address) gives you the range reference with two dollar signs, e.g. `$C$1`, and the [`.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.split) part outputs only the letter, e.g. `C`.


As a side note, instand of [`sheet["A1"].expand("right")`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.expand), it would be also possible to use `sheet["A1"].expand()` or [`sheet.used_range`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/sheet.html#xlwings.Sheet.used_range).